# Cannot invoke Parse method of System.Version

Tags: powershell-2.0

In a PowerShell script, when I try to parse `[System.Version]::Parse("1.2.3.4")`
I get this error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Version] doesn't contain a method named 'Parse'

I have PowerShell 2.0 and NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: `[Version]"1.2.3.4"`

Comment: Thank you! I was more strict... ;)

Comment: Just to know, why has to be like this? In other powershells I could use 'Parse' method

Comment: According to the error message you're getting the `Version` class on that system doesn't have a static method `Parse()`. Maybe different PowerShell or .Net framework versions on the different systems.

Comment: `Parse()` was added in .NET 4.0